# Powershell Copy-Item gives 2 different results for same path

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

## The issue

---

I'm writing a deployment script using powershell. Using the `Copy-Item` command doesn't provide the same result between runs, even with the same data. (It doesn't seem idempotent)

See the results below for an example of what I mean. I realize that I could delete the files in `C:\products` before copying the "new" version in, but I'm more curious as to whether this is expected behavior in Powershell or not. (And I'm assuming it is)

I'd rather learn the 'correct' way to use `Copy-Item` instead of hacking around my lack of knowledge.

I've tried using the `target\*` path instead of `target` but that exploded my `lib` folder into the root of `showcase`, which I didn't expect even with the `-Recurse` flag.

```
C:\products
  - showcase
    - showcase.jar
    - logback.jar
    - foo.jar
    - junit.jar
    - etc, etc
```

I'm also a little confused with the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1) (specifically examples 7,10, and 11) as 7 uses the `-Recurse` flag while 11 does not. Meanwhile example 10 says this:

> If the scripts folder contains files in subfolders, those subfolders will be copied with their file trees intact.

but never specifies a recurse flag either.

---

## The results

### Before deployment

```
C:\products
  - backup
```

### Initial deployment

```
C:\products
  - showcase
    - showcase.jar
    - lib
      - <dependencies for showcase.jar>
  - backup
    <empty>
# Expected, as there wasn't a prior deployment yet.
```

### Second Deployment

```
C:\products
  - showcase
    - showcase.jar
    - lib
      - <dependencies for showcase.jar>
    - target
      - showcase.jar
      - lib
        - <dependencies for inner showcase.jar>
  - backup
    - showcase
      - showcase.jar
      - lib
        - <dependencies for "old" showcase.jar>
  # Expected, the old version was backed up
```

---

## Deployment script and how it's called

```
./deploy.ps1 -hostname foobar (it's a remote server)
```

#### deploy.ps1

```
param( [String]$hostname, [switch]$debug )

$folder_to_copy = "target"
$init_file = "./init.ps1"

function Backup-Binary ( [String]$source, [String]$name, [String]$dest ) {

    $FullyQualifiedSourcePath = "$source\$name"

    if (Test-Path $FullyQualifiedSourcePath) {
        Write-Host "Backing up $FullyQualifiedSourcePath to the destination $dest"
        Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $FullyQualifiedSourcePath -Destination $dest -ErrorAction Stop
    } else {
        Write-Output "Directory $FullyQualifiedSourcePath didn't exist. May be an initial deployment. Continuing with deployment."
    }

}

function Verify-Env ([String]$env_var) {
     $check = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($env_var)
     if ($check -eq $null) {
         Write-Error "$env_var environment variable doesn't exist. Exiting program."
         exit 1
     }
}

function Deploy-Local {

    # Checks that the given string exists as an Environment variable
    Verify-Env "DEPLOY_DRIVE"
    Verify-Env "CI_PROJECT_NAME"

    # C:\products or D:\products *most* of the time.
    $root = "$env:DEPLOY_DRIVE\products"
    $destination = "$root\$env:CI_PROJECT_NAME"
    $backup_loc = "$root\backup"

    # Removes prior binaries
    Backup-Binary -source $root -name $env:CI_PROJECT_NAME -dest $backup_loc

    # Copy binary locally since we're deploying to local machine.
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $folder_to_copy -Destination $destination -ErrorAction Stop

    # Run the init script the developer has written
    Invoke-Expression "$init_file" -ErrorAction Stop

}

function Deploy-Remote {

    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostname

    $DEPLOY_DRIVE = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 
        [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("DEPLOY_DRIVE")
    } -ErrorAction Stop

    $root = "$DEPLOY_DRIVE\products"
    $destination = "$root\$env:CI_PROJECT_NAME"
    $backup_loc = "$root\backup"

    Write-Host "$root = root $destination = destination $backup_loc = backup_location"

    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:Backup-Binary} -ArgumentList $root,$env:CI_PROJECT_NAME,$backup_loc -ErrorAction Stop

    Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -ToSession $session -Path $folder_to_copy -Destination $destination -ErrorAction Stop

    Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath $init_file -ErrorAction Stop

    Remove-PSSession $session -ErrorAction Stop

}

if ( $hostname.ToLower() -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME.ToLower() ) {

    Deploy-Local

} else {

    Deploy-Remote

}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `robocopy` rather than trying to script the copy logic yourself. (No sense in reinventing the wheel.)

Comment: I had no idea about that! Luckily that is available for the machine running the deployment script so I guess that's the silver bullet for me. I would still like to see any suggestions though, more knowledge is never a bad thing in my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This answer is given by @mklement0 from the [provided link](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7005#issuecomment-395111414) (an issue I started on github)

> @huffstler:
>
> Yes, but that is the same problem as #2934, just in the context of a larger command:
>
> - When subdir. a is being copied, $b doesn't exist yet, so a's content is being copied directly into $b (behavior (a) above).
> - By the time subdir. b is copied, $b already exists, and that's when the inconsistency kicks in: b's content is copied to $b/b (behavior (b) above).
>
> Therefore, if you run the command again, you do get the desired behavior.
>
> Given the current behavior, you can work around the problem as follows:
>
> ```
> Get-ChildItem -Path $a |
> ForEach-Object { New-Item -Force -Type Directory $b } { 
>   Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $_.FullName -Destination $b
> }
> ```
>
> But the larger question is whether this inconsistency should be resolved toward behavior (a) or behavior (b).
>
> You clearly expected (a), but others may have different expectations, based on xcopy.
>
> Frankly, I was baffled to find the same inconsistency as with Copy-Item -Recurse in the Unix world (cp -R).
>
> The only way to currently get predictable behavior is to:
>
> - Ensure that the target dir. already exists.
> - Then, depending on whether you want behavior (a) or (b):
> - To get behavior (a): Explicitly target the content of the source directory:
>
>   `Copy-Item -Recurse -Force $a/* $b`
>
>   - Note the need for -Force, which is needed to ensure that hidden items are copied too.
>   - With cp on Unix, you can more simply just `$a/.`, but that doesn't work in PowerShell.
> - To get behavior (b): No further action needed.